# Is there a URL parameter that will make the URL open in a specifically named browser window

Tags: html, email, url, parameters, href

I have an email digest that is sent daily to users of my website and contains links to things on the site so that they can easily get right in and start interacting from their email. Trouble is, if they click more than one link, they're going to be opening more than one browser and the non-technical user might not catch that and end up having to close a bunch of tabs/browsers when they're done on the site. I want all the links in the email digest to be opened in the same window/tab.

I know that if you have an `href` you can set `target=my_window` and the links will open in that window. I'm wondering if there's a URL parameter that can be used instead of editing the `a` tag.

Comment: keep in mind that users may also be using third party email applications to view email. Most of these probably have built in web browsers, but some aren't going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the `window.open` method?

[**Reference:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `window.open(url, name, features, replace);`

It allows a ***browser window*** to be **named**, and thus ***reused*** when clicking on new links that are formatted to work with the `window.open` syntax.

**Example:** [**link**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp)

**Status Update:** Note you can search for many [**window.open(); Online Generators**](http://www.google.com/search?q=window.open+generator) to help build the look of the opened window. It's important to test the desired look in all browsers, as the Address Bar in each browser is rendered differently.

Answer (score 3):

No. I don’t know of any browser (or other user agent) that associates any special behaviours with link query strings. The query string is for the server receiving the HTTP request to deal with.

As you say in your question, the `target` attribute is the method for controlling (or at least suggesting) what window the link should open in.

Comment: I figured, but thought I'd make sure anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Paul D. Waite, the `window.open();` method is **alive and well**. Check out this most ***awe-inspiring*** and extensive use of this method for a Chrome (and Mozilla) [**Google Lab Demo**](http://thewildernessdowntown.com/). Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics: **yes**, that’s ***very true*** — when I said that `target` is the way to open links in specific windows, I meant as far as HTML goes. I’d be leery of going down the JavaScript route even for e-mail newsletters though, as I wouldn’t rely on e-mail clients running `javascript:` URLs. And if you’re putting the JavaScript in an `onclick` attribute, you may as well stick with `target` unless you want to change the features of the window.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  This behavior you are talking about is strictly client side, controlled by the browser.  The application running on the web server is responsible for reacting to the query string.

Do you not have control over the template of the e-mails that are sent?  It should be trivial to add the target to the appropriate anchors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to catch custom URL parameters.

Say you have a link like:
www.yoursite.com/somepage.php?title=Some Page Title Here

The paramater string in the URL starts with ?something=somevalue and can be chained with the & symbol (e.g. ?something=somevalue&somethingelse=someothervalue) etc.

You can then ad this PHP to the top of your page:

```
<?php $title = $_GET['title']; ?>
```

Then for your title tag put the following:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

You would add another variable with the value of the param for each param you want to pass in to the page. But for what you're trying to do, the above code will work.

Comment: “for what you're trying to do, the above code will work” — if I understand correctly, the OP is trying to make sure that all links within an e-mail open in the same browser window. I’ve no idea how your code achieves that.